# Anatomical changes form biped to quadruped

Tags: science-based, biology

I have a character that changes from a bipedal human to a quadruped. The change is a result of extreme surgery with magic to support it. I know there are multiple anatomical changes that need to happen but don’t know the specifics.

**What are the anatomical changes that need to occur to change from biped to quadruped?**

Comment: Can you please clarify the nature of the "change" your character undergoes? Is this a sort of high magical / sci-fi type transformation where she just instantly becomes one form or another (sort of like going through a ST transporter); or is this an actual physical process? If this is physical, is it wand-wavey magical or are we talking adding / subtracting / stretching on the molecular level? I'm voting to close your question until you can clarify the nature of the Change in your world, so that you won't end up with a dozen different cool but possibly off the mark answers.

Comment: @elemtilas I already did the question asks for ANATOMICAL changes.

Comment: I get that you want a list of anatomical changes. What I'm asking to be clarified is the nature of the change itself. Depending on how this works in your world, there may not be any actual changes that occur.

Comment: The change itself is not important. That would make the question too broad and is irrelevant to my worldbuilding at this point.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around! Knowing how your world works --- the rules the underlie the Change --- will actually focus what is now an extremely broad and unfocused question. As for what is relevant to your worldbuilding at this point, only you know that. What I'm trying to do here is help you understand what is relevant in this community for those of us who want to help you. If you don't want the help, that's fine!

Comment: @elemtilas I don't understand what clarification you're asking for here, or why it's needed to answer the question. Whether it's Star Wars surgery, a Star Trek teleporter accident or Harry Potter potions seems irrelevant. Voted to reopen since I do not understand the close reasons and the question seems answerable, focused, and on-topic.

Comment: @JamieB --- Those are all exceptionally relevant factors to know, and is precisely what I'm getting at. We need to know whether this some kind of magical transformation that simply poufs into existence a new physical form (no anatomic changes required), or is this some kind of transformational process where bones change shape and tendons & muscles have to painfully reshape themselves and relocate themselves (anatomic changes happen). As written, the query suggests a one step process. 0. I'm a biped 1. I'm a quadruped. The answer is obviously "no anatomic changes are required, as (cont)

Comment: (cont) everything just sort of instantly changes. Or, it could be, "loads of anatomic changes happen because of X, Y, & Z". Or it could be "only 2 or 3 anatomic changes are needed." Basically every answer is equally valid. If we know the *underlying rules* for how the Change works, then we can come up with a very cool and probably rational answer. This is basic WB.SE question writing. I'd love to answer this query! But unfortunately, the OP demands specifics --- but will *give no specifics in return!*

Comment: I think the real problem with this question is that the real answer would be horribly tedious. "fuse metatarsals and extend ... reduce femur length ... strengthen hip flexor muscle ... increase spine length and strengthen ..." There is nothing we could provide besides the initial research that OP should have done himself.

Answer (score 2):

As humans evolved from our very distant ancestors, our skeletal structure changed to adapt to the upright, biped walking. There wasn't just one change that happened, and most of it was on the lower body, so let's look into it.

**Foot**

Purpose:

Our foot changed from another part of our body used for gripping onto things, to now a part of our body that now holds up our entire weight. Because of this, our feet became more arched, along with getting smaller toes, because they're not mainly used for balance instead of gripping.

What to change:

Increase the size of the foot, allowing for more surface area of grip. Increase the size of the toes, to again, allow for more surface area of grip. And lastly, while not entirely necessary, you could change the foot from arched to flat, as the reason we developed arched feet was to take more strain of our spine and on our feet as we became biped.

**Knee**

Purpose:

The knee has been enlarged in order to account for the more bodyweight. As well as the degree of knee extension, which both accounts for the more bodyweight as well as improving balance.

What to change:

Increase the degree of knee extension, as balance wouldn't be as important on all fours. As less bodyweight is going to be pushing on the knees, their size wouldn't need to be as large, too.

**Limbs**

Purpose:

Our legs have increased in length due to both the push required for walking being moved to the ankle, as well as allowing for a natural swing of the leg while walking. This frees up our arms for uses other than transportation, which decreased the muscle mass, relative to modern-day humans and our very distant ancestors.

What to change:

Decrease the length of the legs, to allow for the arms to reach the ground while still maintaining a somewhat upright posture. Increase the muscle mass of the arms, to allow it to support the weight of the body. And lastly, decrease *some* of the muscle mass of the legs, as some of the strength required would be moved to the arms.

**Hips & pelvis**

Purpose:

Our hip joints are larger, to again allow it to support the weight of the body better. Along with that, the placement of the vertebral column was moved closer to the hip, to decrease the amount of effort required to balance.

What to change:

Make the pelvis larger and broader, to allow for the legs to have a more open posture, as we have less of a degree of hip extension. Push the vertebral column more forward, as again, balance isn't too important when on all fours.

Comment: Don't forget all the changes to the shoulder/arms/hands to make them load bearing. Plus to need a place for the hand to bear the weight, your hands don't bend far enough to support a stride.

Comment: Also probably worth mentioning that most large quadrupeds are digitigrades, that is, they walk on their fingers (bears being a notable exception to this rule), while humans are plantigrades, our feet are flat against the ground.